# Python: Script runs another script while redirecting stdout

Tags: python, redirect, stdout, os.system

I am trying to run a script (first.py) which runs another script (second.py).

I know I can use the following within first.py:

```
os.system("second.py inputFile.xml")
```

However by calling second.py it generates stdout messages. I wish to not display those messages and just store them as a list of strings for use within first.py.

What would my first.py look like?

Comment: use `subprocess.Popen` (or `subprocess.check_output` , if your python is >= 2.7)

Comment: If you are writing the first script, why not just `import` the second script and call the required functions directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

import second

old_stdout = sys.stdout # temporarily stores stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

second.func("inputFile.xml")
```